# Logstash reading SQL Server data real time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Is there any way I can configure logstash so that it picks up delta records real time automatically. If not then is there any opensource plugin/tool available to achieve this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below configuration for the MSSQL server. You need to schedule it like below by adding the schedule period, a statement which would the query to fetch the data from your database

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "sasa"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\abhijitb\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.2.2.jre8\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    #clean_run => true
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    #query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM Student where studentid > :sql_last_value"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "studentid"
    }
}

output {
  #stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "student"
  "document_type" => "data"
  "document_id" => "%{studentid}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont have any primary id in my table. Neither any combination of columns can do so. In this case how would i make sure to insert only new rows in second scheduled run?
Aslo, why are we using use_column_value attribute here?

Comment: @pradyumn do you have a time stamp on  your table when records are updated?